# Opencv rectangle gets drawn on original image (unable to remove)

Tags: python-3.x, image, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I used the cv2.rectangle() function to draw a rectangle around my image. This works fine. However, I realise that it is also drawn on my original copy. (I made two copies of the same image from my original image file). Can someone please point out where I went wrong?
Here's the code (left out chunks to reduce length):

```
img=cv2.imread(file,1)
height, width = img.shape[:2]
max_height = 800
max_width = 800

#some image resizing function
#...
resized=img

originalImg=resized
height0, width0=resized.shape[:2]
image=resized

#image manipulation on (image)
#...

imageRect=cv2.rectangle(image,(xCoor,yCoor),(xCoor+width, yCoor+height), (255,0,255), 3)
#This shows the drawn on rectangle fine
cv2.imshow("imageRect", imageRect)

#problem is, this originalImg still has the rectangle drawn on it
cv2.imshow("originalImg", originalImg)
```

Comment: you have to use .copy() resized = img.copy()

Comment: ohhhhh thanks a lot!!

Comment: you are welcome :)

Comment: thanks for asking this question, had same problem :)